# Open new tabs to the right in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to use Sql Server Management Studio 2008 R2. When I open a new-query tab it opens to the LEFT of the other tabs and pushes all open tabs to the right (thus changing their position every time I open a new tab). This is extremely frustrating, I don't really understand this design choice.

How can I make SSMS 2008 R2 tabs behave "normally" (open new tabs to the right, so existing tabs stay stationary)?

Comment: Is there a solution for this for Windows 10?

Answer (score 21):

Lemurr has answered it, but just so that any one using SSMS 2016 (April Preview) can find it.
Microsoft has now moved this from

*Tools > Options > Environment > Documents > Insert documents to the right of existing tabs*

to

*Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs.*

Answer (score 9):

If the UI is the same as in 2012, it should be in `Tools > Options > Environment > Documents > Insert documents to the right of existing tabs`

Comment: I came across this fix during a google search, unfortunately that option doesn't exist in 2008 R2 (at least not in that location).

Comment: I have the same situation with 2008 R2.

Answer (score 4):

For SSMS 18, its under *Environment* > *Tabs And Windows*.

Answer (score 4):

I see varying navigation options for old and newer versions of SSMS.  Below is the navigation for SSMS v18.5 with screenshots.

Tools --> Options (Opens Options Window) -->  Environment --> Tabs and Windows: Under the Tab Well section header check the box next to 'Insert new tabs to the right of existing tabs'.

[image: TabsOpenOnTheRightScreenshot]

Screenshot of the SSMS version for the tool itself which is what we are discussing aka Client Tool SSMS not the DB version however I'm not sure if that plays into the differences in menu navigation.  Help --> About:

[image: SSMSv18.5]

Answer (score 2):

For SSMS v 17.9.1, this feature can be configured at Tools > Options > Environments

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed any other settings of the layout then simply reset it by going to `Window > Reset Window Layout`